# MFC: Accelerators for Ctrl-Shift don't work?

Tags: winapi, acceleratorkey

I have some accelerators configured and if using just the `Ctrl` key it works fine, but if I make it `Shift`+`Ctrl` it doesn't work (doesn't even show as a shortcut in the MFC menus where as the `Ctrl` version does).  The entries I've tried with both upper and lower case letters, doesn't make a difference.  This is what the entries in the accelerators look like:

```
"R",            ID_R1,        VIRTKEY, CONTROL, NOINVERT
"R",            ID_R2,        VIRTKEY, SHIFT, CONTROL, NOINVERT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I made the "R" capital above because of the two answer talking about that, but I originally had "R" and only changed to "r" before giving up and asking here.   But the "R" doesn't work for Ctrl-Shift-R either, where as the Ctrl-R works fine?

Edit: Using Spy x64 and checking the main window, never get a command sent.  If I go to the list view on the right side of a splitter window and press Ctrl-Shift-R in that order, the only thing generated is:

```
<000041> 00000000002100D6 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_CONTROL cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000042> 00000000002100D6 S LVM_GETNEXTITEM iStart:-1 flags:LVNI_SELECTED
<000043> 00000000002100D6 R LVM_GETNEXTITEM iIndex:-1
<000044> 00000000002100D6 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:2A fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000045> 00000000002100D6 S LVM_GETNEXTITEM iStart:-1 flags:LVNI_SELECTED
<000046> 00000000002100D6 R LVM_GETNEXTITEM iIndex:-1
<000047> 00000000002100D6 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'R' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:13 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:1
<000048> 00000000002100D6 S LVM_GETNEXTITEM iStart:-1 flags:LVNI_SELECTED
<000049> 00000000002100D6 R LVM_GETNEXTITEM iIndex:-1
<000050> 00000000002100D6 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:2A fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000051> 00000000002100D6 S LVM_GETNEXTITEM iStart:-1 flags:LVNI_SELECTED
<000052> 00000000002100D6 R LVM_GETNEXTITEM iIndex:-1
<000053> 00000000002100D6 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_CONTROL cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

Edit:

Even more data, I placed a conditional breakpoint in thrdcore.cpp at line 178 where the message loop is (the line is `if (pState->m_msgCur.message != WM_KICKIDLE && !AfxPreTranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur)))`).  The break point is: `pState->m_msgCur.message==0x0100 && pState->m_msgCur.wParam==0x52` (WM_KEYDOWN for R).   When pressing `R` or `Ctrl-R` the breakpoint hits, when pressing `Ctrl-Shift-R` the breakpoint doesn't occur.   Above spy trace there is never a WM_KEYDOWN for the R, only an up?

Edit:

Now really getting weird.  I decided to go in to the keyboard settings for VS2017 and see if something assigned to Ctrl-Shift-R, I press it and nothing happens, I try any other letter like Ctrl-Shift-T and it works fine.  Could it by my keyboard?  Or something deeper in Win10 x64 that is eating a WM_KEYDOWN for R when Ctrl-Shift is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: Virtual keys represent physical keys, not characters. There is no "lowercase r" key on the keyboard. The key on the keyboard is an uppercase R. It happens to produce a lowercase r when you press it, but that's not what virtual keys represent.

Comment: I had originally had the "R" but changed to "r" as a test.   But the "R" version doesn't work either.  It doesn't show up in the MFC menus as available either, only the Ctrl-R version.   Should the Ctrl-Shift version be "VIRTKEY" or something else?

Comment: @RaymondChen Update original message with spy and conditional breakpoint. WM_KEYDOWN never received for the R only up?  Any hints on what to look for?

Comment: The other discussion says that Ctrl+Shift+N works. This suggests that some program has registered Ctrl+Shift+R as a global hotkey, which overrides your accelerator.

Comment: @RaymondChen Is there a way (even undocumented) to find what has that key sequence registered?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the title names of accelerator keys and menu items are not updated is that the registry information is not updated.

There are two solutions for your reference:

First, you can manually delete the information in the registry.You can enter the registry area:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Local AppWizard-Generated Applications

Then delete the registry information of your current application name, and it will work normally after recompiling the program.

In the second method, you can clear the registry information by adding the [`CleanState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinappex-class?view=msvc-160#cleanstate) function to the `ExitInstance()` function. After restarting the program, the key information and menu bar information of the current program will be updated.

You can refer to:

```
int CMFCApplication1App::ExitInstance()
{
    //TODO: handle additional resources you may have added
    AfxOleTerm(FALSE);
    this->CleanState();
    return CWinAppEx::ExitInstance();
}
```

And both solutions worked for me.

Comment: Yes, now the menu item has the Ctrl-Shift-R showing next to it, but it still doesn't work pressing those keys whereas the Ctrl-R does.   It's a splitter window with a CTreeView on the left and a CListView on right, also top has CMFCToolBar and CMFCToolBar.  The MessageMap is within the CMainFrame.  Is there some issue using Shift-Ctrl under a splitter window?  I've tried with the active pane being one or the other and never get the OnID2 call using the accelerator.

Comment: I added spy data to original question above and also added conditional breakpoint result that WM_KEYDOWN never received for the R on the Ctrl-Shift-R.

Comment: @user3161924 Ctrl-Shift-R worked for me after I tested it, have you tested whether other keys work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use upper-case characters in the accelerator table:

```
"R",            ID_R2,        VIRTKEY, SHIFT, CONTROL, NOINVERT
```

To show the shortcut keys on the menu, you have to modify the menu item itself, like change

```
MENUITEM "&New\tCtrl+N",                ID_FILE_NEW
```

to

```
MENUITEM "&New\tCtrl+Shift+N",          ID_FILE_NEW
```

Comment: I've just modified the wizard-created app, `File New` command with `"N", ID_FILE_NEW,  VIRTKEY, SHIFT, CONTROL, NOINVERT`; it now works with `Shift+Ctrl+N` and doesn't work with the default `Ctrl+N`. You must be doing something wrong

Comment: the menu item now has it listed as it should (it's automatic in MFC), but pressing the key still not working.  The original question updated with spy data when pressing the key combination.